# essential reading for php coding (including databases)?

Tags: php, new-operator

I'm dabbling in a bit of php coding with databases and am getting a bit stuck with relationships and the like. Can anybody reccomend some books, online or real, that would be a good start for someone new(ish) to php and mysql databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few I have found helpful:

- [PHP and MySQL Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166)
- [Core Web Application Development with PHP and MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131867164)
- [PHP in Action: Objects, Design, Agility](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=object+oriented+php&x=0&y=0)
- [Database Design for Mere Mortals(R): A Hands-On Guide to Relational Database Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752840)

Comment: looks useful, thanks. I'd mark this as an answer but I need 15 rep...too bad I can't "borrow" it from other sites.

Answer (score 1):

[The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) is an excellent resource.  The online version is searchable and has a lot of user contributions as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have programming experience I would recommend the Zend PHP Certification Study Guide which will give you a quick intro.

Answer (score 0):

php object oriented solutions, teaches you how to think oop using php